# doMPI error: There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2 slots that were requested by the application

Tags: r, parallel-processing, osx-yosemite, openmpi, dompi

I'm trying to get the doMPI package running on my local machine, so that I can perform testing on it before submitting jobs to a cluster. I am using Mac OSX Yosemite and have installed open mpi 2.0.2 via brew.

> mpirun -V
>
> mpirun (Open MPI) 2.0.2
>
> Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/

I have read over the introduction for doMPI and I'm trying to execute the example in the demo

> mpirun -H localhost R --slave -f sincMPI.R

Unfortunately I get keep getting the following error. I've googled around but can't seem to figure out what might be wrong.

```
> Loading required package: foreach Loading required package: iterators
> Loading required package: Rmpi
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2
> slots that were requested by the application:  
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript
> 
> Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
> available for use.
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = rscript, slavearg = args, nslaves =
> count,  :    MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes Calls:
> startMPIcluster -> mpi.comm.spawn -> .Call Execution halted
> ------------------------------------------------------- 
> Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned a non-zero exit code.. 
>Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
> -------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero
> status, thus causing the job to be terminated. The first process to do
> so was:
> 
>   Process name: [[27630,1],0]   Exit code:    1
```

EDITED: Results of test based on the answer below

Worked as specified:

```
mpirun -H localhost,localhost,localhost R --slave -f sincMPI.R
```

I took out the count=2 from startMPIcluster() and it also worked.

```
startMPIcluster() #in sincMPI.R 
mpirun -H localhost,localhost,localhost R --slave -f sincMPI.R
```

If you take out the count=2, you can vary the number of hosts in mpi run. Here I specify four hosts.

```
startMPIcluster() #in sincMPI.R 
mpirun -H localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost R --slave -f sincMPI.R
```

You can even use this method to specify more than the number of available cores. I have 8 (logical) cores, but I can specify 9 hosts and it runs.

```
mpirun -H localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost,localhost R --slave -f sincMPI.R
```

However, you can't put count=9 into startMPIcluster()

```
startMPIcluster(count=9)  
Error in startMPIcluster(count = 9) :    
  count must be either unspecified, or set to 8 
Execution halted
```

So, perhaps the best approach for testing mpi on a mac is to not set count in startMPIcluster, and use -H to control the number of tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the mpirun `-H localhost` option, the MPI universe size is only one, and that is causing `mpi.comm.spawn` to fail when the example calls `startMPIcluster`. If you use `-H localhost,localhost,localhost`, the universe size will be three and the example should work.

---

*Update*

Note that I only call `startMPIcluster` with a count argument when executing interactively on a single computer (that is, when I'm *not* using mpirun). When executing a doMPI script with mpirun, I find it easier to control the number of workers via mpirun.

Comment: This worked well, thank you! I did a few experiments just to see how MPI works on a mac. Just for the record, I'm putting the results in the original question.